# Google Drive and Chrome Web Store authentication

Tags: google-drive-api, chrome-web-store

I am building a Chrome Web Store application with the Google Drive API, and am wondering how I should authenticate the user.

The Chrome Web Store documentation recommends using the OpenID.

The Google Drive SDK documentation recommends using oauth2.

Should I support both? If a user logs in with OpenID, and then opens a file from Google Drive, is there a way I can know that the OpenID and oauth authentications should be linked to the same account?

Comment: I thought they share same authentication scheme... good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that The Chrome Web Store only "recommends" to use OpenID (v2 I guess). However Drive forces the use of OAuth 2.0 when you create or open a file from Drive. I would recommend that you then use OAuth 2.0 based authentication - which is called OpenID Connect - since it is compatible with Drive and since you don't have to use Chrome auth. You can simply trigger the OpenID Connect (OAuth 2.0-based) authentication flow from your web application when users are not coming fro Google Drive but are coming, for instance from the New Tab page in Chrome.

The only notable exception I can think of is if you are using Chrome's billing API, then you might have to use OpenID v2.

In short: Use [OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) (which is OAuth 2.0 based) since Drive forces you to use it and since it is also a more recent technology.